# Can You Defragment with Help of a Separate Drive on XP?

Tags: windows-xp, defragment

So basically I have a drive that I've tried to clean up, but I still cannot get enough continuous space on it for files to defragment properly, so can I use another drive with a lot of extra space to rearrange the files so that they can then be copied back to the defragging drive as contiguous files?

If I can, how would I be able to do this?

Comment: why the hassle, move some stuff temporarily off that hard drive, defraggle it and then move the files back.

Comment: Interesting idea Dennis, but I agree with Molly. The end result is the same, the process is similar. Only difference is the amount of hassle setting it up.

Comment: Take the sane route that Molly suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NTFS is fairly good at keeping files contiguous if:

- the drive is big enough
- the files are copied over onto a freshly formatted disk

So I would do what Molly suggested in the comments: move the pr0n and videos to the other, bigger drive (which will be reasonably contiguous), defrag the main drive with [Defraggler](http://www.defraggler.com/), and move them back again (though I wouldn't even bother moving them back if the second drive is a permanent solution).

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to try an alternative defragmenter, download the trial version of Diskeeper. It defrags with as less as 1% free space.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently with a drive that was completely full and would not boot.

I mounted the drive in another machine and moved (hidden) Uninstall directories and service pack files from C:\windows to another drive, which gave enough free space to boot. Then, I used [Cleanup!](http://cleanup.stevengould.org/) to clean out IE caches (amazingly, there were still caches for *old* versions of IE), disabled hibernation and moved the swap file to another drive. Defragged, updated and ghosted.